# Помогите с анализом текста

Tags: анализ-текста

Здравствуйте уважаемые дамы и господа, меня собираются лишить водительских прав за установленный ксенон, статья 12.5, ч. 3.

3. Управление транспортным средством, на передней части которого установлены световые приборы с огнями красного цвета или световозвращающие приспособления красного цвета, а равно световые приборы, цвет огней и режим работы которых не соответствуют требованиям основных положений по допуску транспортных средств к эксплуатации и обязанностей должностных лиц по обеспечению безопасности дорожного движения, влечет лишение права управления транспортными средствами на срок от шести месяцев до одного года с конфискацией указанных приборов и приспособлений.

Судья посчитала что "световые приборы, цвет огней и режим работы которых не соответствуют" нужно трактовать как альтернативу, то есть и цвет огней и режим работы приводит к нарушению по данной статье, мне соответственно нужно доказать обратное.

Есть ли кто-нибудь на форуме, кто может сделать полный лингвистический анализ данной статьи?

Comment: Эта платная процедура. Адресок могу подкинуть. Но смысла большого не вижу. Вы же не в конституционном суде собираетесь оспаривать. А в остальных случаях лингвистическая экспертиза нужна на предмет наличия в нем оскорблений или клеветы. Здесь вам ничего не выгорит.

Comment: НУ если надо будет и Верховного и до Конституционного дойду. Адресок озвучте пожалуйста.

Comment: Сейчас, найду. А что адвокат, сам мышей не ловит, что вы сюда пришли?

Comment: http://www.rusexpert.ru/. Должны сделать,  в крайнем случае скажут, к кому бежать. Детали - на сайте посмотрите.

Comment: Спасибо, письмо написал, пока жду ответа все же надеюсь что и здесь мне кто-нибудь сможет помочь

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

> Спасибо, письмо написал, пока жду ответа все же надеюсь что и здесь мне кто-нибудь сможет помочь

Каким образом? Ну я скажу, что вы правы, тут, если подходить с позиций формальной лингвистики, должен быть союз "ИЛИ". А юридически все равно будут толковать по смыслу. Ибо в вашей трактовке закон получается бессмысленным. Ну глупо же карать человека, только если ***одновременно*** два нарушения.

Тем более если написать ИЛИ, то всегда найдется умник, который скажет, что у меня сразу два нарушения, а в статье сказано "или" - "или".

Делать Вам нечего. Вот что. Наймите нормального адвоката, хотя я и не люблю эту братию... Он найдет более благодарную линию защиты. Тут вы ничего не словите, я вас умоляю.

Comment: а что мешало написать и(или), или так и/или ?